# Jump to definition in Xcode cannot jump to the right overloaded function. Is this a bug? Is there any workaround?

Tags: xcode11

Instead of jumping to the right overloaded function, it shows all the similar functions in a pop-up menu, which is not helpful. Often the overloaded functions differ by the number of parameters, thus there is no ambiguity in parameter identification. I am using Xcode 11.5 but this problem has been around for a while. Do you know if this is a bug? Is there any workaround?